# Mongo db Search on IP Octet based

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a entry in mongo db collection like

```
{ ip : "10.291.231.198" }, {ip : "104.192.200.121"}
```

I need to search a result on octet based , like i want to search 4th octet

I tried

```
db.test.aggregate([{"$match":{"$and":[{"ip":{"$regex":"\.\.\.\.19"}}]}}])
```

which returns both the result whereas i only want the first one .

Comment: Try `"$regex":"[.]19[0-9]*$"`

Comment: thanks  @WiktorStribiżew its working :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
"$regex":"[.]19[0-9]*$"
```

It will find a record ending with `.19` with any 0+ trailing digits.

**Details**

- `[.]` - a dot
- `19` - a literal `19` substring
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.